# Как правильно написать условие с указанием в value нескольких параметров?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такой код

```
<select class="weui_select" id="id_count">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
```

Как правильно в значений value задать несколько других параметров

```
<option value="id_a=123 id_b=322 id_c=713 id_di=479 id_e=23012 id_f=7020">1</option>
```

или так

```
<option value="id_a=123" "id_b=322" "id_c=713" "id_di=479" "id_e=23012" "id_f=7020">2</option>
```

или как то по другому?

Comment: Синтаксически, конечно, первый вариант. Но смотря что Вы собираетесь потом делать с этими данными. Потому что по факту это всё равно одно значение, хоть и состоящее из множества символов с пробелами.

Comment: В китайском безымянном роутере вписать часть настроек оператора через это поле. Не уверен, что смогу это вписать в яваскрипт файл с описанием через XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

Лучше все доп. значения которые нужно собрать, после того как пользователь выбрал определённый пункт, храните в отдельном объекте. Не нужно пихать всё в верстку. И когда пользователь выбирает данные просто по выбранному значению получаете нужный Вам объект / массив значений (всё что нужно пихаете туда).

**Пример ниже:**

```js
const select_cont = document.getElementById('id_count');

const ObjData = {
  1: {
    a: 123,
    b: 456,
    cs: 4356
  },
  2: {
    d: 12223,
    r: 4543436,
    ts: 43244256
  },
  3: {
    a: 123,
    b: 456,
    cs: 4356
  },
  4: {
    d: 12223,
    r: 4543436,
    ts: 43244256
  },
  
}

select_cont.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if (ObjData.hasOwnProperty(e.target.value)) console.log(ObjData[e.target.value])
  else console.log('Данные не заданы');
})
```

```html
<select class="weui_select" id="id_count">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```